# Is there a way to provide a relationship between many variables displayed in facets in tmap? E.g. showing multiple variables on one interactive map

Tags: r, shiny, leaflet, r-sf, tmap

I am trying to show the population of all different age groups in a map. Is there a way to show this information NOT in facets. But instead group together on a single interactive map?

Below is a reproducible example with the NLD_muni dataset on CRAN. The tmap part produced the different populations in facets. Just copy and paste:

```
library(spData)
library(spDataLarge)

data(World, Europe, NLD_muni, NLD_prov, land, metro)

tm_shape(NLD_muni) +
  tm_fill(c("pop_0_14", "pop_15_24", "pop_25_44", "pop_45_64", "pop_65plus"),
          style="kmeans", 
          palette=list("Oranges", "Greens", "Blues", "Purples", "Greys"),
          title=c("Population 0 to 14", "Population 15 to 24", "Population 25 to 44",
                  "Population 45 to 64", "Population 65 and older")) +
  tm_shape(NLD_muni) +
  tm_borders()
```

I was potentially thinking if this is not possible in tmap. Is there a way to structure the dataset differently so i can do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply add:

```
+ tm_facets(as.layers = T)
```

after `tm_borders()` and use view-mode via `tmap_mode("view")`.
Then you can select the individual entries  via the check boxes in the legend.

[image]

Comment: Hi would you also know how to out these values in percentages? i.e. when you click on a specfic area. It will show the population of 0-14, 15-24 in relation to a percentage of each other? e.g. You click on the bottom area and of the total there are 10% 0-14, 30% 15-24, 70% 25-44